# how to capture online audio stream or get its url?

Tags: html, audio

When access the website:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/propensity

Click the "pronunciation" button, it will pronounce the word.

But I could not find the url of the audio file from the page source of the webpage.

Is it possible to get the url of the stream file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one maps to http://www.macmillandictionary.com/media/british/uk_pron/p/pro/prope/propensity_British_English_pronunciation.mp3.

You can find it under the **Network** tab of your favorite debugger (firebug, chrome console, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to find, on row 237:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/media/british/uk_pron/p/pro/prope/propensity_British_English_pronunciation.mp3

But I'm quite sure Macmillan Publishers Limited won't like you copying their audio files. They own the content of their site.